# bond0:0 + define virtual IP

Tags: linux

in my Linux server I have the following:

Linux Version - RedHat-Linux- 5.3.0.0

(this Linux server only only one LAN)

```
   more /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond0:0

   DEVICE=bond0:0
   ONBOOT=yes
   BOOTPROTO=static
   IPADDR=10.10.10.12
   NETMASK=255.255.255.0




 ifconfig -a
           bond0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00  
           UP BROADCAST MASTER MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
           RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
           TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
           collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
           RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)

           bond0:0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00  
           inet addr:10.10.10.12  Bcast:1.1.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
           UP BROADCAST MASTER MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

           eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0E:0C:C7:F8:92  
           inet addr:1.1.1.1  Bcast:1.1.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
           inet6 addr: fe80::20e:cff:fec7:f892/64 Scope:Link
           UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
           RX packets:8600 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
           TX packets:4764 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
           collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
           RX bytes:717979 (701.1 KiB)  TX bytes:598620 (584.5 KiB)
           Memory:b8820000-b8840000
```

my problems:

1. why I get HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00 and not the real MAC address
2. I cant ping to other server with 10.10.10.11 from my server
3. is it possible to define bond0:0 when I have only one LAN (eth0)

other info:

more /etc/modprobe.conf

```
 alias eth0 e1000e
 alias eth1 e1000e
 alias eth2 e1000e
 alias eth3 e1000e
 alias scsi_hostadapter mptbase
 alias scsi_hostadapter1 mptsas
 alias scsi_hostadapter2 ata_piix
 alias bond0 bonding
 alias bond1 bonding
```

Comment: By the usual naming conventions bond0:0 would be an aliased interface for the primary bond0 interface. Do you have config files that bond 2 or more other interfaces into bond0?

Answer (score 0):

When: HWaddr (MAC address) is 00:00:00:00:00:00

Check the configuration

**Step 1**

/var/adm/autoinstall/scripts/eth_alias.sh

```
eth0 3,0,0 Update
eth1 6,0,0 Fabric1
eth2 6,0,1 Fabric2
eth3 13,4,0 Base1
eth4 13,4,1 Base2
```

**Step 2**

and update the bonding values of Fabric1 and Fabric2 in `/etc/sysconfig/network/ifcfg-bond1` file

```
BONDING_SLAVE0='bus-pci-0000:06:00.0'
BONDING_SLAVE1='bus-pci-0000:06:00.1'
```

**Step 3**

```
rcnetwork restart
```